# Why are constants in Java the way they are?

Tags: java, enums, constants

I have read about Java enums and use them regularly. However, I don't understand why e.g `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` returns an `int`.

Considering http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html;

```
// int Enum Pattern - has severe problems!
public static final int SEASON_WINTER = 0;
public static final int SEASON_SPRING = 1;
public static final int SEASON_SUMMER = 2;
public static final int SEASON_FALL   = 3;
```

*Not typesafe - Since a season is just an int you can pass in any other int value where a season is required, or add two seasons together (which makes no sense).*

`JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` returns **3**, while `JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE` returns **1**, which means three of the latter equals the first.

**Why is it implemented this way?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Java didn't have enums [until 1.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_5.0_.28September_30.2C_2004.29) - most of these constants were introduced earlier, and if they were changed to enums Sun would've broken a lot of existing code.

Comment: Elsewhere in Swing, the enum "pattern" is used without language support.

Answer (score 3):

Those constants were probably added to the standard library before enums were added to the language. Enums were added in [Java 1.5](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html). To maintain backwards compatibility, they left old constants how they were.

Answer (score 3):

Enums are a recent addition to Java. Changing all of the old integer constants to enums would've broken a lot of existing Java code.

Answer (score 1):

The link that you provided says:

```
In prior releases, the standard way to represent an enumerated type was
the int Enum pattern:

// int Enum Pattern - has severe problems!
public static final int SEASON_WINTER = 0;
public static final int SEASON_SPRING = 1;
etc...
```

Java Swing (JFrame) was available much earlier.